# Перезагрузка страницы при изменение ширины браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так что, если размер окна браузера по ширине меняется с текущего к примеру до 720px (если ширина такая или меньше, то перезагрузка), при таком разрешение страница перезагружается? Если с 720рх меняется обратно в большую сторону, то тоже перезагрузка?
Пожалуйста подскажите как написать на javascript.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87492/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir-rodichev----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерно так можно сделать задуманное.

В первую очередь когда загружается страница мы в переменной скидываем текущий размер окна, Что бы потом проверить не вылезло ли ширина окна из текущей территории (что бы сделать перезагрузку.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cur_width = $(window).width();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() <= 720 && cur_width > 720){
            //reload
            location.reload();
        }
        else if($(window).width() > 720 && cur_width <= 720){
            //reload
            location.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: А `location.reload()`  поленился дописать? )))

Comment: @Air Вообще то мне показалось ему логика была нужна, А если команда перезагрузки то же была важна, Значит опять мой ответ вполне хватает. ))))))(пусть почитает доки)

Comment: @Air Если вам несложно, можете свой пример привести? Я так понимаю, что нужно написать эту функцию после условия?

Answer (score 2):

```
    window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 576 && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 768) {
        console.log('md');
    } else if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768 && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 992) {
        console.log('lg')
    } else if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 992) {
        console.log('xl');
    } else {
        console.log('sm')
    }
};
```

вот мое решение